# Passing props to children components with react-router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-component

Previously in react-router v3.* I passed props to children components via

```
React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props)
```

How is this done in react-router v4 with the new `<Match />` API

So far the solution I've come up with is to use the `render` method in the `<Match />` API:

```
<Match pattern="/" render={() => <ChildComponent {...this.props} />} />
```

using the ES6 spread syntax to pass props to Child Component. Is there a better way which also carries with it all the standard props (location, pattern, pathname, isExact) to the child component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by [the render code of v4.0.0-alpha5](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v4.0.0-alpha.5/modules/Match.js#L87-L95), you have the following two options:

```
<Match pattern="/" render={props => <ChildComponent {...props} {...this.props} />} />
<Match pattern="/">{({matched, ...props}) => {
    return matched ? <ChildComponent {...props} {...this.props} /> : null;
}}</Match>
```

Also see the [Match API documentation.](https://react-router.now.sh/Match)

Comment: I'm using react-router v4.0.0-2 as I'm not sure how stable the alpha versions are. I guess react-router v4 is still generally in development, I've noticed even that npm only ship v3 unless you explicitly ask for version 4

Comment: It seems like the relevant rendering code is the same in alpha-2. But yeah, I think v4 is still very experimental. If you're looking for something stable, I'd use v3 instead.

Comment: Yh it is. Didn't realise props were arguments passed into render function. Thanks! This is probably the best solution at the moment